# Equation confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help solving the following:
$S_{0} \Delta-f=\left(S_{0} u \Delta-f_{u}\right) e^{-r T}$

is equal to

$f=S_{0} \Delta\left(1-u e^{-r T}\right)+f_{u} e^{-r T}$

My own guess is: $f=S_{0} \Delta\left(S_{0} u \Delta-f_{u}\right) e^{-r T}$ but i know (looking at lecture slides) that another way of phrasing the right answer, is $f=S_{0} \Delta-\left(S_{0} u \Delta-f_{u}\right) e^{-r T}$. I do not understand why there is a minus in front of the parenthesis.

Comment: If $\alpha -f = (a-b)c$ then $f-\alpha = (b-a)c$ and $f=\alpha +(b-a)c=\alpha-(a-b)c.$

Comment: Why isnt that: $f=\alpha+(a-b)c$? I need to remove the negative in f, and when i do that, i need to multiply -1 to both sides?

Comment: If you have $A-f=B$, multiply both sides by -1 to get $-A+f=-B$ (note the minus sign on $B$), add $A$ to both sides to get $f=A-B$. Alternatively, from $A-f=B$ add $f$ to both sides to get $A=B+f$, then subtract $B$ from both sides to get $A-B=f$ and then just swap sides.

Comment: Was going to write exactly that $\cdots.$  Another idea:  try plugging in some numbers:  $a=3, b=2, c=1, \alpha=10,$ for example.

Comment: Ah there it was. Thank you very much guys :-)